# Какой  способ  связи  в словосочетании  -стрижка  карэ  и почему?

Tags: словосочетания

Какие  ещё  есть  примеры, где  способы  связи  не  определяются  традиционным  правилом?

Answer (score 2):

http://rusq.ru/?p=808

Примыкание - вид подчинительной связи, при котором зависимость подчиненного слова выражается не грамматически, а лексически (по смыслу), порядком слов и интонацией. Примыкают только неизменяемые знаменательные части речи: наречие, инфинитив, деепричастие, простая сравнительная степень прилагательного (дети постарше), неизменяемое прилагательное (цвет хаки, цвет беж, стрижка каре), существительное – несогласованное приложение (в газете «Известия»), притяжательные местоимения его, её, их (его рубашка) .

Answer (score 1):

Объяснение простое: примыкают неизменяемые части речи, поэтому здесь явное примыкание. Примыкают также наречия, деепричастия, инфинитивы, местоимения "её, его, их"